# When creating multiple React Components in a loop with an incrementing counter passed as a prop, why does the counter show the final value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, closures

I'm trying to understand how closures work in javascript.

Here, I'm iterating through values of the 'items' array using a foreach. I've a let variable "count" declared outside the scope of the foreach loop. After each iteration, the value of 'item' is added to 'count'. Inside the loop, I'm declaring a new React Component that renders the value of "count".

```
export default function App() {
  const comps: ComponentType<any>[] = [];

  let count = 0;
  const items = [5, 1, 3];

  items.forEach((item) => {
    const countCopy = count;
    comps.push((props) => (
      <div>
        {count} : {countCopy}
      </div>
    ));
    count += item;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {comps.map((Comp) => (
        <Comp />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I run the code, the count value that is showed is its last value (9). I need to create a copy "countCopy" of the variable in order to display its current value. Why is that? Is there a cleaner way?

CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-closure-question-5uwmm

Comment: `count` is outside the loop, it only exists once, not once for each component. All five will therefore use the current value.

Comment: Think of it like there were 5 individual `countCopy` variables. Each one gets set during its turn in the loop, but here is only 1 `count` that all 5 components use.

Comment: If you don't push a function inside the for loop but push the `<div>` instead, then render `<div className="App">{comps}</div>` you'll get the expected result.

Comment: You'll get the expected result from @ChrisG's comment because of *when* the variables are evaluated. Since you're pushing a function, the variables are evaluated **after** the `forEach` loop has completed (during the returned `map`). If just pushing JSX, the variables will be evaluated **during** the `forEach` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution using reduce instead of foreach:

```
export default function App() {
  const comps: ComponentType<any>[] = [];

  const items = [5, 1, 3];

  items.reduce<number>((count, item) => {
    const countCopy = count;
    comps.push((props) => (
      <div>
        {count} : {countCopy}
      </div>
    ));
    return count + item;
  }, 0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {comps.map((Comp) => (
        <Comp />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The "count" that is rendered is assured to be the current value, since it is declared inside the loop

https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-closure-question-solution-8ping

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a "solution". It's essentially the same. Both the `forEach` and the `reduce` are unnecessary if all you're trying to do is get the count of the current element (its just the array index + 1). You could do all of this in the `map`

Comment: The real answer to your question *why does the counter show the final value* - is because the function returned from your loop is not called until the render, which means the variable `count` is not evaluated until it has its "final" value. All the `reduce` does is put `count` in a different scope (the same as `countCopy`).

Comment: A map wouldn't work, since I need to know the previous value of count to increment it.

Comment: I see now why the `map` alone would not work, the question before the edit did not make that clear.